# Laravel 5.6 Function () does not exist in route/web.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is my code using to send an email

```php
Route::post('/mail/send', [

    'EmailController@send',

]);
```

in `EmailController` this is the send action

```php
public function send(Request $request)
{    
    $data = $request->all();
    $data['email'] = Input::get('email');
    $data['name'] = Input::get('name');

    $obj = new \stdClass();
    $obj->attr = 'Hello';

    Mail::to("dev@mail.com")->send(new WelcomeEmail($obj));
}
```

getting a error as `Function () does not exist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your route/web.php file

Change it to

```
Route::post('/mail/send', 'EmailController@send');
```

Refer to the documentation to see the possible options to define routes:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

Answer (score 1):

In your route ...

```
Route::post('/mail/send','EmailController@send')->name('send_email');
```

Inside of your HTML form add below code...

```
<form action="{{route('send_email')}}"     method="post">
...
{{csrf_field()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Route's action method can be defined using a array, but not simply wrap `controller@action` in an array, you should assign it to array's key `'uses'`.

In your example, it should be like this:

```
Route::post('/mail/send', [

    'uses' => 'EmailController@send',
    //'middleware' => .... assign a middleware to this route, if needed
]);
```

the array form usually is used when we want to specify more specification about the route like use a specific middleware and pass middleware parameters.

if you just want to define route's processing method you can simply use `controller@action` as `Route::post`'s second parameter:

```
Route::post('/mail/send','EmailController@send');
```